# Lattice basis and adjoint lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is Artin alegra chapter 14, M.9 excercise

> Consider the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^k$, with dot product $(v \cdot w)$. A lattice $L$ in $V$ is a discrete subgroup of $V^+$ that contains $k$ independent vectors. If $L$ is a lattice, define
> $L^* = \{(w \mid (v \cdot w) \in \mathbb Z$  for all $v \in L\}$.

> (a) Show that $L$ has a lattice basis $B = (v_1, . . . , v_k)$, a set of $k$ vectors that spans $L$ as $Z$-module.

> (b) Show that $L^*$ is a lattice, and describe how one can determine a lattice basis for $L^*$
> in terms of $B$.

> (c) Under what conditions is $L$ a sublattice of $L^*$ ?

> (d) Suppose that $L \in L^*$. Find a formula for the index $[L^* : L]$.

The question is easy if $L$ has a orthogonal basis $B = (v_1, . . . , v_k)$

$B^* = (v_1/(v_1 \cdot v_1), . . . , v_k/(v_k \cdot v_k))$ and
L is a sublattice of $L^* \iff 1/(v_i \cdot v_i) \in \mathbb Z$  for all $k$

$[L^* : L]$ =  $\prod 1/(v_i \cdot v_i)$

But I cannot figure out how to handle general case.

Comment: What is $V, V^+$ and the group structure on $V^+$?

Comment: @RichardAshcroft I think here V is the space $\mathbb R^k$ and $V^+$ mean the law of composition of the group is vector add

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf B=\{v_1, v_2,v_3...v_k\}$ be the $k$ independent vector in L.
This is also the basis of $\mathbb R^k$

For(a), the proof is following the same manner as Lemma 6.5.8.

We build the lattice base $\mathbf B'=\{v'_1, v'_2,v'_3...v'_k\}$ from $\mathbf B$

Let $\ell = L \cap span(v_1)$. This is not empty and is discrete group in   $\mathbb R_1$ so have the form of $\mathbb Zv'_1$

$v'_k$ Select from the manner than has the coordinates regards
$$(a_1v'_1, a_2v'_2...a_{k-1}v'_{k-1}) \mid 0<a_i\leq1$$ has the minimal lenth.

For(b), let $\mathbf E$ is the normal stardard basis of $\mathbb R^k$
So the lattice basis $\mathbf B = \mathbf EP$
The $$\mathbf B^*=\{v^*_1,v^*_2...v^*_k \}$$
$$(v^*_i, v_j) =
\begin{cases} 0 & i\neq j 
\\ 1 & i=j 
\end{cases}$$ is the basis of $L^*$
$$\mathbf B^*=\mathbf E(P^T)^{-1}$$ is exsit as $P$ is the basis transform matrix.
We can easily examine this meet the requirement.
We also get that
$$\mathbf B^*=\mathbf BP^{-1}(P^T)^{-1}$$
For (c) $L\subset L^*$ when every $v_i $ has intger coordinate on $\mathbf B^*$ basis.
$$\mathbf B=\mathbf B^*P^TP$$
$P^TP$ is integer matrix.

For (d)
$$[L^* : L] =det(P^TP)$$